# Force CKEditor to add a class to p-tags

Tags: css, ckeditor

I must configure CKEditor to add a class-attribute to every p-tag in the content. You can do something similar with config.format_p but it will only apply the class-attribute to text that is marked as "normal" which is not default.

Edit:
I'm using the current version 3.6.2. Here are the relevant parts of my config:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{   
    config.removeFormatTags = 'b,div,big,code,del,dfn,em,font,i,ins,kbd,q,samp,small,span,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,u,var,form,input,textarea';

    config.format_p =
    {
        element: 'p',
        attributes:
        {
            'class': 'tiny_p'
        }
    };
    config.skin = "office2003";
    config.entities_processNumerical = true;
}
```

The `config.format_p` option only takes effect when user chooses "normal" from format-menu and `config.removeFormatTags` only works when user manually clicks the clean-button. Both should work automatically like it does in TinyMCE.

Comment: What version of CKEditor? What is your config so far?

Comment: @HerrSerker updated that in my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add html processor filter

```
editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules({
    elements :{
        p : function( element ){
            if ( element.className.indexOf("thiny_p") < 0){
                element.className += 'thiny_p';
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Also, if it is not required to be created as ckedito plugin maybe before you send content to server you can use jQuery to change content

```
$("iframe", "#cke_editor1").contents().find("p").addClass("tiny_p");
```

or, if textarea (source) is active

```
var editor= $("textarea", "#cke_editor1"); 
editor.val(editor.val().replace(/<p>/gi, "<p class='thiny_p'>"))
```

you should tweak a bit `.replace(/<p>/gi, "<p class='thiny_p'>")` regular expression to support other cases.

#### EDIT

Finally got time to download and setup editor on my box, here is working plugin

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'customparagraph',
{
    init: function( editor )
    {
        editor.addCommand('addParagraphClassName',{
            exec : function( editor ){    
                var ps = editor.document.$.getElementsByTagName("p");
                for (var i=0; i < ps.length; i++){

                    if(ps[i].className.indexOf("thiny_p") < 0){
                        ps[i].className += "thiny_p";
                    }

                }

            }
        });

        editor.ui.addButton( 'ThinyP',{
            label: 'Appends thiny_p class',
            command: 'addParagraphClassName',
            icon: this.path + 'images/icon.gif'
        });
    }
} );
```

put it in `plugins/customparagraph/plugin.js`
also create icon image `plugins/customparagraph/images/icon.gif`

in configuration you will have to add following configuration options config.js of you CKEdito installation

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
    config.extraPlugins = "customparagraph";
    config.toolbar = [ [ 'ThinyP' ] ]; // add other toolbars and keep in mid this can be overwritten in page which loads CKEditor
};
```

**OR**

in page which loads CKEditor

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
    // instance, using default configuration.
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1',
        {
            extraPlugins : 'customparagraph',
            toolbar :
            [
                [ 'Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Link', 'Unlink' ],
                [ 'ThinyP' ]
            ]
        });
//]]>
</script>
```

User will have to click on toolbar button before save

Comment: Is there a way to configure this in config.js? Because there is not quiet anything else I have access to. So your (probably quiet good) suggestion with jQuery is no alternative as well.

Comment: One way is to create your plugin and in init method add  `editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules({ ...`. After that just include plugin in your config.js. Second solution is ok but I presum you will have some issues since you have to hook to every possible situation when edited text is gonna be send to server and at that point apply this jquery fix (i would try first solution if you ask me) :)

Comment: Thank you, gonna try that tomorrow.

Comment: Well, doesnt work. I've got a plugin which is included and put your script in the init-function of it but does not seem to effect anything.

Comment: Nope. Just nothing happening.

Comment: And that is the problem. The user has to click it. The CKEditor will be used in a system with about 2000 users and they will not click any buttons before saving. This is the only problem with CKEditor while migrating from TinyMCE and it seems like it will be the reason why it can't be used... Anyway, thanks a lot for your work, I'll mark your answer as the solution to get you the bounty :)

Answer (score 2):

Well .. not sure if you need that for some specific reason .. but wouldn't life be much easier if you do what you want to do at the display end?

Like if I display some text (saved from ckeditor) at the front end, display in something like a

```
<div class="ckcontent" > ... </div>
```

And all

```
 <p>
```

tags within it can be applied styles or applied jquery by the notation:

```
 .ckcontent p { margin-left:5px;........ }
```

OR

```
 $('.ckcontent p').addClass('ckparagraphs');
```

Comment: No, I can't do any manipulations on the frontend. I do not have access to that and they expect the content to look like that. Can't change anything about that.. p-tags must be saved with the class "tiny_p".

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, and after a while of messing around I finally found a one-line solution:

```
config.format_p = { element : 'p', attributes : { 'class' : 'yourClassName' } };
```

All you need to do is put this code in `config.js` and it will work :)

Comment: Do this add the class 'yourClaseName' automatically or does the user have to select 'normal'? Thanks.

Comment: This works for me. But I will find a better solution for that. thanks.