# How to add class or attribute automatically to img tags in CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor version 3.6

I want to automatically add `class="newsleft"` to any image tag added through the WYSIWYG.

I've seen a few posts that mention dataProcessor but have no idea which file this should be added or how to do it.

Can someone tell me where I would place the following code?

```
editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules(
{
    elements:
    {
        img: function( element )
        {
            if ( !element.attributes.alt )
                element.attributes.alt = 'An image';
        }
    }
} );
```

Comment: Try to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836349/force-ckeditor-to-add-a-class-to-p-tags the answer is pretty detailed

Answer (score 11):

Basically put it in [`instanceReady`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-instanceReady) listener and it will be fine (3.x and 4.x) ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/PZHyq/1/)):

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
    plugins: 'wysiwygarea,toolbar,sourcearea,image,basicstyles',
    on: {
        instanceReady: function() {
            this.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules( {
                elements: {
                    img: function( el ) {
                        // Add an attribute.
                        if ( !el.attributes.alt )
                            el.attributes.alt = 'An image';

                        // Add some class.
                        el.addClass( 'newsleft' );
                    }
                }
            } );            
        }
    }
} );
```

[CKEDITOR.htmlParser.element.addClass](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.htmlParser.element-method-addClass) is available since CKEditor 4.4. You can use `this.attributes[ 'class' ]` prior to that version.

Comment: Your fiddle is no longer working with CKEditor 4.10.1 when using the image2 (enhanced image) plugin instead of the default image. Any guidance how to achieve it...?

Also refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52689549/ckeditor4-enhancedimage-plugin-image-added-event-or-how-to-add-custom-class-to

Answer (score 9):

Here's another approach:

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( evt ) {
  evt.editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules( {
    elements: {
      img: function(el) {
        el.addClass('img-responsive');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: only this worked for me, I'm using ckeditor v.4.9.2 with backpack for Laravel

Comment: this approach works well when the images are first added. But if open in edit, and save, the added class is lost. Any idea?

Answer (score 6):

this worked for me in 3.6

add the following code to config.js

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function (ev) {
    // Take the dialog name and its definition from the event data.
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

    // Check if the definition is image dialog window 
    if (dialogName == 'image') {
        // Get a reference to the "Advanced" tab.
        var advanced = dialogDefinition.getContents('advanced');

        // Set the default value CSS class       
        var styles = advanced.get('txtGenClass'); 
        styles['default'] = 'newsleft';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of this topic is being found in Google very high, I might help people by answering the question: how to add a default class when inserting an image in CKeditor. This answer is for CKeditor 4.5.1. as this is the latest version right now.

1. Look up image.js in /ckeditor/plugins/image/dialogs/image.js
2. Search for d.lang.common.cssClass
3. You will find: d.lang.common.cssClass,"default":""
4. Edit it with your class name(s) such as: d.lang.common.cssClass,"default":"img-responsive"

I've tried this and it works!

Answer (score 0):

in Version: 4.5.3

1. Look up image.js in /ckeditor/plugins/image/dialogs/image.js
2. Search for editor.lang.common.cssClass
3. You will find: editor.lang.common.cssClass,"default":""
4. Edit it with your class name(s) such as: editor.lang.common.cssClass,"default":"your-class-name"