# How to prevent a block style to propagate onto following block when deleting new lines in CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, wysiwyg

When there are 2 blocks with style applied to then and you delete an empty line between them the lower block's style is lost and overwritten by the previous block's style. How to prevent this? I want the styles to remain unchanged and just remove the line break.

Here's an example of what I'd like to prevent the editor from doing:

[image: CKEditor bug]

```js
var editor = document.getElementById('editor');
 CKEDITOR.inline(editor);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.0/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
<div id="editor" contentEditable>
  <p></p>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
</div>
```

I've googled extensively but can't find any mention of this behavior or how to clearly describe what this behavior is called. Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's kinda of expected result, since you delete a `H1` element and the previous element is a `P` tag in your snippet.

Check this snippet in which the previous element is also a `H1`

```js
var editor = document.getElementById('editor');
 CKEDITOR.inline(editor);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.0/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
<div id="editor" contentEditable>
  <h1></h1>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
</div>
```

If you inspect the HTML and then delete you will see that in your example the `H1` element is indeed deleted and its content is moved into the previous `P` element.

Comment: The behavior I was looking for is for the previous empty block to become the same block style as the line I am currently on.

Comment: Hi @Dave. Well, if you run my answer snippet and apply italics only for the `<h1>` element, and then delete the `<h1>` line, the previous element will have italics applied. Try it with the element inspector on Chrome and you can check this out.

Comment: In your snippet this applies too. If you set italics to the header and delete, paragraph will be italicized.

Comment: How to extend this to work the same with block styles then?

Comment: I just checked, styles are implemented by `style` attribute, not classes. There are examples on the web for setting up classnames to specific tags, this would clean a bit of the styling. The only way I found to make it work out of the box is to preselect both blocks and apply style to those, then delete the later block.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836349/force-ckeditor-to-add-a-class-to-p-tags may help.