# CKEditor set Attribute by getElementsByTag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, getelementsbytagname, setattribute

I have to insert a new class and ID and other attributes to the element by `getElementsByTag` Method at CKEditor.

```js
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(event) {
  var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor;

  editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules({
    elements: {
      $: function(element) {
        if (element.name == 'blockquote') {
          if (!element.attributes.class) {
               //element['class'] = 'block';
               element.attributes.class = 'block'  
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Input:

```
<blockquote>
  <p>(b) Any information recorded or stored by means of any tape-recorder, computer, or other device; and any material subsequently derived from information so recorded or stored.</p>
</blockquote>
```

Required Output

```
<blockquote class="block" id="bq001">
  <p>(b) Any information recorded or stored by means of any tape-recorder, computer, or other device; and any material subsequently derived from information so recorded or stored.</p>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: This link should help you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836349/force-ckeditor-to-add-a-class-to-p-tags)

Comment: `$('.cke_contents iframe').contents().find("blockquote").addClass("block");`

Comment: **For custom attribute**
`$('.cke_contents iframe').contents().find("blockquote").attr( 'class', 'myClass' );`